Python Project not able to post on schedule time on Facebook or Instagram using Django
not able to post on schedule time on Facebook and Instagram with schedule time i am able to post but i need to sort the schedule time issue not any error appears.
Here is the code
(VIEWS.PY)
def index(request):

    post_form = BasicForm()
    
        if request.method == 'POST':
            post_form = BasicForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
            
            try:
                if post_form.is_valid():
                    fss = FileSystemStorage()
                    file = fss.save(request.FILES['post_file'].name, request.FILES['post_file'])
                    file_url = fss.url(file)
                    post_description = post_form.cleaned_data['post_description']
                    is_schedule = post_form.cleaned_data['schedule_check']
                    
                    if is_schedule:
                        schedule_time = post_form.cleaned_data['schedule_time']
                        
                        if schedule_time:
                            # Ensure schedule_time is timezone-aware
                            if timezone.is_naive(schedule_time):
                                aware_schedule_time = timezone.make_aware(schedule_time, timezone.get_default_timezone())
                            else:
                                aware_schedule_time = schedule_time
                            
                            SchedulePost.objects.create(
                                post_description=post_description,
                                post_file=file_url,
                                fb_check=post_form.cleaned_data['fb_check'],
                                insta_check=post_form.cleaned_data['insta_check'],
                                whatsapp_check=post_form.cleaned_data['whatsapp_check'],
                                schedule_check=True,
                                my_datetime=aware_schedule_time,
                            )
                            
                            logger.info(f"Scheduled time (selected): {aware_schedule_time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z')}")
                            logger.info("Record scheduled...!")
                            
                            return redirect('index')  # Redirect to index after scheduling

(SETTING.PY)
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Karachi'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True

Kindly let me know if any more details are required
[28/Jun/2024 02:17:11] "GET /index/ HTTP/1.1" 200 13741
[28/Jun/2024 02:17:54] "POST /index/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
Tried : The first step is to add USE_TZ = True to your settings file.
Also tried the naive_datetime aware as well
